# Color Image Watermarking with a Grayscale Watermark

Tags: image-processing, matlab, watermarking

I'm currently working on a project on digital watermarking in a color image. The host image is a color image, and the watermark image that will be embedded is a gray.
Is it necessary that the watermark will be a color image to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may convert it into RGB gray image by just replicating it along the color channels.

In MATLAB, given `mG` as the gray image it would be

```
mGRGB = repmat(mG, 1, 1, 3);
```

Then you may proceed with the regular procedure.

Comment: Thank you your answer :)

Comment: it's already done my friend ;-)